# Facebook Login fails on first attempt to get session

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I'm having issues with my Facebook Login using PHP SDK.

I have if else statement for the session variables as I also use this login to store user info to db, like name, email and uid.

Problem I'm getting is on first login, code will always execute the ELSE statement for the session which executes the the script that says "Please try to login again", then when the user try to login again, it will be successful. I need help fixing this so user will be recognized on first attempt.

Also, my login button is being accessed via:

```
href="example.org/fb-redirect.php"
```

Thanks!

```
<?php

include('debug.php');
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/templates/initialize.inc");

session_start(); 
$curtimestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // added in v4.0.0 
require_once 'fb/autoload.php';     
require_once('fb/src/Facebook/GraphUser.php');   
use Facebook\FacebookSession; 
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper; 
use Facebook\FacebookRequest; use Facebook\FacebookResponse; 
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException; 
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException; 
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException; 
use Facebook\GraphObject; 
use Facebook\GraphUser; 
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken; 
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient; 
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable; 

function authoLogin($userLogin){    
$global_connection = db_connect();  
$userdata = db_getrow("select * from user where user_login like '".$userLogin."'", $global_connection);     
db_query("update user set user_loginerror=0 where user_id='".$userdata['user_id']."'", $global_connection);     
util_setsessionvar('usertype',$userdata['usertype_id']);    
util_setsessionvar('userid',$userdata['user_id']);  
util_setsessionvar('userlogin',$userdata['user_login']);    
util_setsessionvar('username',$userdata['user_name']); 
} 
// init app with app id and secret 
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'appid','secret' ); 
// login helper with redirect_uri

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://example.org/fb-redirect.php' ); 
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {   
// create new session from saved access_token   
$session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

 // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid   
try {
    if ( !$session->validate() ) {
      $session = null;
    }   
} catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // catch any exceptions
    $session = null;   
  } 
}   
if ( !isset( $session ) || $session === null ) {   
// no session exists
     try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();   
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
    // handle this better in production code
    print_r( $ex );   
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    // handle this better in production code
    print_r( $ex );   
   }    

} 
// see if we have a session 
// see if we have a session 
if ( isset( $session ) ) {   
//store the token in the php session   
// graph api request for user data   
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );   
$response = $request->execute();   
// get response   
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::classname());
        $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
        $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
       $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID         $fgetid=$graphObject->getID();      //get image source from facebook account
       $getimgsrc='https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fgetid.'/picture?width=200';

       /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
        $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;      $_SESSION['PROFILE_PICTURE']=$getimgsrc;        $_SESSION ['form_data']['return_url'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'];


  if statement {
        //save to database
       } else if statement{       
}
    /* ---- header location after session ----*/

}else{  
echo "<script> alert('Please try to login again'); window.location.href='index.php'; </script>"; 
}
```

Comment: I guess on first try there is no variable $session set. But before reload the $session is set to null. Now it will be picked up by your if statements on next reload and not on first attempt.

Comment: I can't really figure out how I can make it recognize on the first time since the user is just doing the same thing, just clicking on the login with fb button. @LarsMertens

Comment: Not sure you need this check before setting $session. if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) )

Comment: @LarsMertens tried to remove the if statement but still same results. I can't figure out why on 2nd login it becomes successful and I just can't let this happen as users might get frustrated with this.

Comment: You just exposed your app id and secret here, which means everybody now has a valid app access token for your app. So the very first thing you need to go do now is reset your app secret via app dashboard.

Comment: Oh yeah! reset done! Thanks! Have any ideas why it cant get session on first login? @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

This can be closed now. Fixed everything by using the latest version of Facebook's PHP SDK. Thanks!